# Crash program when using google play service api for accessing google map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I am trying to access Google map by using google play service api . I do every step form this tutorial [URL]:http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/ 
. I check any recheck my code many times which is exactly[which i copied from this tutorial] like this tutorial. But my app crash when i run both in emulator and my phone. Please see the code given in the tutorial. Is there any problem in this code or i am in the wrong path. If so please give any other better option . Thanks in advance .. :)
 my logcat showed like this

```
07-07 07:13:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(963): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 07:13:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(963): Process: com.example.trymap2, PID: 963
07-07 07:13:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(963): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.trymap2/com.example.trymap2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
07-07 07:13:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
07-07 07:13:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
07-07 07:13:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-07 07:13:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
07-07 07:13:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-07 07:13:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-07 07:13:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
07-07 07:13:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 07:13:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-07 07:13:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
07-07 07:13:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
```

Comment: @user3730885 are you testing this on emulator?

Comment: @todd i edited my question with the logcat(here i given few lines from logcat ). please see it :)

Comment: @QadirHussain i try both in samsung galaxy s3 and my emulator both platform it crash :(

Comment: check your layout file.. you have error in layout.xml(whatever name).. also check fragmentmanager or supportfragment, or view.findviewbyid()...

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar can you please visit this link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/  . i just copied code form this link. i already checked everything u asked but don,t get solution.please see the xml file there :)

Comment: Re-create the layout file, check it for BOM marker and for non-UTF8 characters. Also this could happen, if you're running out of memmory, but that's not likely your current problem.

Comment: Hey guys i found the answers.....just add following code i overcome my problem...thanks all for try to help me :)

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
    />